# File is executed twice if plugin is activating

Tags: php, plugin-development, debug

I have an issue with my plugin. I run an function if the plugin is activating this function include a file. But if I activate the plugin the file is included twice. Is this normal or an bug in Wordpress? Is there an solution for this?

In the main file I do this

```
if ( file_exists ( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/autoload/autoloader.php' ) )
{
    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/autoload/autoloader.php';
}
```

Comment: You'll need to share code to get feedback, the description is not enough.

Comment: I added the code what I use in the main file of the plugin.

Comment: Not sure about the issue you are having here, If you want code to run on plugin activation, check this hook - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/

Comment: An autoloader would normally need to be run on every request. Why does this need to only run once, or only on activation? Also, under what circumstances would this file not exist? Why are you checking for its existence?